# Bootstrap 4 navigation tabs content not showing content on initial page load

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-4

On initial page load, the tabs show but the content for that selected tab does not.

If I click the "Link" tab and back to the "Post" tab then it shows up.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="active nav-link" href="#post" data-toggle="tab">Post</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#link" data-toggle="tab">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="post">post</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="link">link</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On page load it looks like this (the div with the `tab-pane` class hasn't been displayed):

[image]

There are no errors in my console and the bootstrap JS file is loaded. There are some similar questions around but the solutions have not worked for me.

What do I need to add to get the tab pane to display when the page loads?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this out

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="card-header">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="active nav-link active" href="#post" data-toggle="tab">Post</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#link" data-toggle="tab">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="post">post</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="link">link</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh. Needed the active class on the div. Cool. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer! I also had to remove `fade` from the default `active` `tab-pane`, in case anyone comes by this.

Comment: 'Active' both on the tab content item and the nav item link did it for me thanks

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of your problem was the fade class. Well done ! Removing it is the solution.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!